# Content of ViewCell does not scroll

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Within my content page I have such XAML:

```
<TableView HasUnevenRows="True" Intent="Form">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection>
            <!-- Height is set intentionally for demo purposes -->
            <ViewCell Height="110">
                <ScrollView>
                    <Editor>
                        <Editor.Text>
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
                        </Editor.Text>
                    </Editor>
                </ScrollView>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

The problem is: text within editor does not scroll, i.e. I can see some lines of text (6 7 8 9), but cannot scroll to other lines. It works fine on iOS. Removing ScrollView does not help. Setting *HeightRequest* to ScrollView or Editor - does not help.

Editor with long text outside of Table and ViewCell works totally fine.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a solution, or is this lack of behavior by design?

P.S. I would like to use StackLayout here, but because of many reasons outside of this example I must use table with cells.

Comment: Version of Xamarin.Forms: 3.4.0.1009999

Comment: I think your TableView (which is scrollable) must intercept any scrolling event. So your cell's scrollview will never receive the scrolling info. I don't know what your constraints are, but generally speaking, having a scollable content inside a scrollable content is not a good idea on mobile. What were your reasons for not using a stacklayout ?

Comment: It is just a badly designed app, which uses tables where stacks should be and I am not in position to change it. But the mentioned example works with iOS. I assume this is a bug in Xamarin. Logically it should be like this: scroll event is handled by Editor, when Editor is in focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't scroll is because of your ScrollView inside your TableView place a stacklayout instead

Xamarin Forms TableView has a scroll by default you don't need to add it manually

Removing the ScrollView will solve your issue

**Update**

If that doesn't work then you might have to do some Custom rendering as Android multiline edittext would be needed cause of the tableview

```
  [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor),typeof(MyEditorRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
    {
      public class MyEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
      public MyEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        int x = (int)e.GetX();
        int y = (int)e.GetY();
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                {
                    Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                {
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                {
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question: "Removing ScrollView does not help".

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will test it tomorrow and will let you know. P.S. I believe I have been trying StackLayout in place of ScrollView without success, but will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Okay no problem also i have added a custom renderer that should help you, just know that your editor should be big enough to have a scroll!

Comment: Using StackLayout does not help.

Comment: Did you check the custom renderer?

Comment: Custom renderer really helped, I have added another answer with minimal code required to achieve the result. Thank you very much fr the help!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an Editor must be located within a scrolling container, add a renderer to Android project:

```
using Android.Views;
using MyApp.Droid.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor), typeof(ScrollForcingEditorRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to force scrolling of Editor in Android
    /// when Editor is located within scrollable container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="EditorRenderer" />
    public class ScrollForcingEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {

        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                // prevent sending scroll event to parent container
                Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }    
}
```